# How to start MySQL transaction that will be committed by mysql_commit()

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, transactions

I'm writing a C++ application that uses [MySQL C API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api.html) to connect to the database. MySQL server version is 5.6.19-log.

I need to run several SQL `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements in one transaction to make sure that either all changes or no changes are applied.

I found in the docs functions [`mysql_commit()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commit.html) and [`mysql_rollback()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-rollback.html) that finish the transaction (commit it or roll it back), but I can't find a corresponding function that **starts** a transaction.

Is there such a function? Am I missing something obvious?

---

I run `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements using [`mysql_real_query()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-real-query.html) function.

I guess I should be able to start the transaction by running [`START TRANSACTION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html) SQL statement using same `mysql_real_query()` function. Then I should be able to commit the transaction by running `COMMIT` SQL statement using same `mysql_real_query()` function.

But then, what is the point of having dedicated `mysql_commit()` and `mysql_rollback()` functions in the API?

Comment: To "start a transaction" you need to disable `autocommit` (MySQL aways has a transaction active, but commits it by default after each statement). There are [several ways](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) to do that, choose the most convenient for you.

Comment: @Vatev, are you saying, that `MySQL C API` function to start a transaction is [`mysql_autocommit()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-autocommit.html) with parameter `mode=0`? Well, it is not quite the same as running `START TRANSACTION` statement. I see a function `mysql_commit()` in the API and expect to have a corresponding function `mysql_start_transaction()` in the API, but it seems there is no such function...

Comment: The difference between using `START TRANSACTION` and setting autocommit is that `START TRANSACTION` disables it only until the next `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: @Vatev, exactly. My question is mainly about this inconsistency in the API. Either I miss something and API has a corresponding function, or indeed there is no API function that is equivalent to `START TRANSACTION` statement, even though there **is** an API function that is equivalent to `COMMIT` statement. The only explanation that I have so far is that nobody really uses this API and nobody cares about this inconsistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like MySQL C API indeed doesn't have a dedicated function that is equivalent of the [`START TRANSACTION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) SQL statement.

The MySQL C API **has** [`mysql_commit()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commit.html) function that does the same as `COMMIT` SQL statement.

The MySQL C API **has** [`mysql_rollback()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-rollback.html) function that does the same as `ROLLBACK` SQL statement.

But, there is no function for starting the transaction in this API.

Answer (score 1):

```
//connect to mysql server:
MYSQL *mysql = mysql_init(NULL);  
mysql  = mysql_real_connect(mysql, ......)

//turn off auto_commit
mysql_autocommit(mysql , false);
```

OR

```
//start a tranaction directly as follows
mysql_real_query(mysql,"BEGIN");

//run your commands:
mysql_real_query(mysql,"UPDATE...");

//commit your transaction
mysql_real_query(mysql, "COMMIT");
```